# Error handling Index + 1 at the end of an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am comparing the index of an array with the value in the next array to check if they are the same. However I am getting an error when I reach the end of the array because I cannot compare it to the next position as it is already at the last index of the array.

```
if (!($scoresArray[$i+1]== $scores))
        {
            array_push($orderedUsers, $userID);
            array_push($processedUsers, $userID);
        }
```

Is there a way to handle the error so that it will continue through the code. I have tried a Try...catch around the if statement but this doesnt seem to work

Comment: `if (isset($scoresArray[$i+1]) && !($scoresArray[$i+1]== $scores))`

Comment: @Rizier123 worked, thanks